# MT03-004 EDA Library

Tags: altium, pcb-fabrication, photodiode, kicad, eda

Currently working on my Honours project, we're designing a wide area sun sensor for an attitude control system of a picosatellite platform. We've elected to implement a COtS quad-photodiode package, specifically the Marktech Optoelectronics MT03-004 (http://www.marktechopto.com/pdf/products/datasheet/MT03-004.pdf), for the optical sensor component of our first prototype and in order to do some early system testing and verification we'd like to be able to fabricate a rig with the photodiode and amplifier on a PCB connected with stripwire to our microcontroller, so we can rotate the PCB in space while keeping our light source fixed. Sorry it's taken me a little long to introduce the context, but here's the question: has anyone fabricated a PCB with this component before? If so, could you please point me in the direction of EDA libraries/files for this device, to be able to lay it out preferrably in Altium, but alternatively in KiCAD? A brief Google search turned up files for other devices from the same manufacturer, but not this one, so if anyone either has any on hand or knows where to find them that would be highly appreciated.

***EDIT***
We've had some comments with regards to the suitability of this particular component for operating in space, we are aware that it's suboptimal for this context, however to clarify: our prototype will not be going into space. At this stage we are simply producing a proof-of-concept, "rough and ready" design. Our scope is restricted as we are undergrads with limited time and budget for the project.

Comment: I would call them  up and ask Vincent Forte, CTO and ask for advice for space qualified parts then EDA details.  You wouldn't want some gamma rays to damage your sensor.

Comment: I dont know what optics you plan to use but a planar quadrature detector is not the optimal method for solar tracking. You want something with orthogonal or off-axis differential detection.

Comment: Your are in all likelihood not going to find it. Learn how to make parts on your own, there is a learning curve and tutorials on how to do this for almost every EDA.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it yourself. It's 5 pins in a circle, and the schematic is 4 diodes.

For the footprint, set the grid using 'Q' to inch, then 'G' and set grid to 0.1" and lay down the 4 anode pins, making sure the pin numbers match the datasheet drawing. Then place the 5th pin at by editing the position to 70.71/70.71 mils. Take care in that the datasheet shows the **bottom** view, looking up at the part, rather than looking down through the part, as almost all do these days. Save in your library with a descriptive name for the component.

For the schematic symbol copy the diodes from a single diode library entry (eg. 1N4148) into a new component. Make sure the pin numbers match the datasheet.Add the footprint (and any other information you wish to add, but at least the comment and a default designator such as 'PD?').

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar detector years ago using a [Hamamatsu S4349](https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/product/alpha/S/4106/S4349/index.html).  It worked for about ±10' tracking up to 15° off axis.  You can get larger angular coverage by spacing your pinhole further from the sensor but you sacrifice resolution (you probably know this).

Here's a couple KiCad parts for your system. https://gist.github.com/sethhillbrand/b83d7c7e6faec2552be2997d235ff560